# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment in Angular 13

Tags: angular

When I click on the `Portfolio` rubric, the page is not running...

[image]

I have an error message in the console which is the following.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'administration/portfolio'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'administration/portfolio'
```

[image]

Here is the structure of the project

[image]

I suspect it's a problem with the route configuration, but I haven't found the problem for several hours.

***app-routing.module.ts***

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: OnlineComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent },
    
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

***app.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        OnlineComponent,
        SigninComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthInterceptor, multi: true },
        { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },

        // provider used to create fake backend
        fakeBackendProvider
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***online-routing.module.ts***

```
const ONLINE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OnlineComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'administration',
        loadChildren: () => import('./views/administration/administration.module').then((m) => m.AdministrationModule),
      },
  
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ONLINE_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class OnlineRoutingModule {}
```

***online.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, OnlineRoutingModule],
  declarations: [OnlineComponent],
})
export class OnlineModule {}
```

***administration-routing.module.ts***

```
export const ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES: Routes = [
 
  {
    path: '',
    component: OnlineComponent,

  }, 
  
  {
    path: 'portfolio',
    component: PortfolioComponent,
  },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(ADMINISTRATION_ROUTES)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AdministrationRoutingModule {}
```

***administration.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, AdministrationRoutingModule],
  declarations: [AdministrationComponent],
})
export class AdministrationModule {}
```

***portfolio.module.ts***

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  declarations: [PortfolioComponent],
})
export class PortfolioModule {}
```

Here is the project [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/kora1348/nini?file=src/app/views/online/views/administration/administration.module.ts).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to registry your inside module routing in your ***app-routing.module.ts*** with *loadChildren*:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ...
    {
      path: 'auth',
      component: AdministrationComponent,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard], 
      children: [
       { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/administration-module.module').then(m => m.AdministrationModule) }
      ]
    }
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

*I think** it's because `AdministrationModule` doesn't know about `PortfolioComponent` since this is in a separate module.

So either unmodularise `PortfolioModule` and import `PortfolioComponent` or lazy load the `PortfolioModule` for the portfolio route and add a simple routing for `path: ""` to `PortfolioModule`.

*routing is hard!